# Cant understand one step of exporting collada skeletal animation

Tags: graphics, export, collada

I have a problem. Finally found a comprehensible guide to the import of Collado. There are equations in the article, which shall be calculated position of verteses in the skeletal animation (full guide - http://thecansin.com/Files/COLLADA.pdf).

> Position = VertexPosition x (Bind Shape x Σ (MatrixPallette [n] x
> Weight [n])) where 0 <= n <4
>
> MatrixPallette [n] = inverseBindPose [n]
> x worldTransforms [n]
>
> worldTransforms [n] = BindPose [n] x
> worldTransforms [parent]

And, behold, like the all clear, but what is worldTransforms [parent] I can not understand (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the worldTransform[parent], is the 4x4 transformation Matrix, of the parent joint. if for example your are looking at a wrist, to get it to the correct position and rotation, you need to apply all the parents' transformations (translations and rotations). So you will need to get the elbows joint worldTransform, the shoulder etc.. work the hierarchical tree upward.